# Applescript progress bar not working

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a properly working progress bar code but when I mix it with some tasks, like copying files here, it gives me error and does not increment, it stops after the first copy, any idea where is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set fileCount to length of selected_items
end tell

set progress total steps to fileCount
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Processing Images..."
set progress additional description to "Preparing to process."
set a to 1

tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to POSIX file "/Users/graphics/Desktop/1"
    repeat with x in selected_items
        set progress additional description to "Processing image " & a & " of " & fileCount
        duplicate x to theFolder
        set progress completed steps to a + 1
        set a to a + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: 1. Did you save it as an Applet? 2. Maybe Finder's selection just contains your script after clicking it? Make a `display dialog x as string` before duplicate to be sure 3. Tell us more about the errors you got.

Comment: I saved it as application, it just stops after the first one, this is the entire script you could run it and see the error if you want

Comment: How do you start the script? Did you try point 2 of my answer?

Comment: I run the script from the script editor, and I am sure the finder selection contain files not the script, did you try this code on your machine?

Comment: Ok, then please start the application by doubleclicking it! But before add an `activate` after your first `tell application Finder`

Comment: I already did that too before but it didnt work, did you try the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the script, **please read the notes below**:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set fileCount to count of selected_items
end tell

set progress total steps to fileCount
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Processing Images..."
set progress additional description to "Preparing to process."
set a to 1

repeat with x in selected_items
    set progress additional description to "Processing image " & a & " of " & fileCount
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFolder to (path to desktop folder as string) & "1:"
        duplicate x to theFolder with replacing
    end tell
    tell me to set progress completed steps to a + 1
    set a to a + 1
end repeat
```

I moved the `set progress...` handlers out of the `tell application "Finder"`-Block because the application "Finder" does not know about the progress bar, and corrected the target folder to match any desktop folder. It works perfectly now, **if**

- The Script is saved as Applet
- The Applet is started via the **Dock**

This is because

- Script Editor cannot take care about the different thread for updating the progress bar when running inside Script Editor
- If you start the Applet via doubleclick inside the Finder, the Applet itself becomes the selection, just because you click it! Starting it from the dock solves this issue!

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Actually the destination folder is just a place holder, I have to change it to somewhere else anyway and my aim with this script is to put it in a service so I can access by right clicking on the selected files, I will try your solution

Comment: I was able to use this in an app that did some things in Mail and it did not require me to open it from the dock. I do have some interactions with the user that the script requires, which puts the Mail app in focus, so maybe that is why. Mail does not recognize the progress indicator similarly to Finder, so having to drop out of Tell Mail was important to make it work.